# Tomcat or cargo is not getting up

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, cargo

I am trying to up the tomcat but I am getting **classNotFoundException** ,
I have tried the different solution from StackOverflow but still, I am not able to resolve the Issue.

here is the exception :-

```
cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.4:start (start-titan-container) @ WebTest ---
01:58:23 [INFO] [2.ContainerStartMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-tomcat:jar:1.6.4 for container tomcat8x
01:58:23 [INFO] You did not specify a container home nor any installer. CARGO will automatically download your container's binaries from [http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/8.5.16/tomcat-8.5.16.zip].
01:58:25 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x starting...
01:58:30 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future
01:58:30 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Oct 09, 2017 7:58:30 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1204)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1338)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2781)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:642)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1472)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:579)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Oct 09, 2017 7:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
01:58:31 [WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (26, 66) : org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Oct 09, 2017 7:58:31 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1204)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1338)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2781)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:642)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1472)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:579)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:644)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Oct 09, 2017 7:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
01:58:31 [WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (26, 66) : org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Oct 09, 2017 7:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
01:58:31 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
02:07:10 [INFO] [yer.DeployerWatchdog] Deployable [http://localhost:9080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [520000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
02:07:10 [WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Deployable [http://localhost:9080/cargocpc/index.html] failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [520000]. The Deployable state is thus unknown.
02:07:10 [ERROR] Starting container [org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat8xInstalledLocalContainer@b039e04] failed, now stopping container
02:07:10 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x is stopping...
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Oct 09, 2017 8:07:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Could not contact [localhost:[9005]]. Tomcat may not be running.
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Oct 09, 2017 8:07:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:576)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:477)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:408)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:497)
02:07:11 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
02:07:16 [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x is stopped
```

Is this related to server.xml file or anything else, Any help would be most welcome, I am stuck because of this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (26, 66) : org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
```

Have a look in the mentioned `server.xml` Tomcat configuration file at line 26. Remove that `JasperListener` — that class does not seem to be distributed with Tomcat 8 anymore.